# Two mouse cursors after lock and switch user on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: mouse, desktop-environments, lock-screen, cursor

Ubuntu 20.10 and all software up to date

Reproducing:

0. Prerequisites: enable **Fractional Scaling** in Settings / Displays and set scale to 125%, 150% or 175%
1. Use shortcut [super + L] / [win + L] or menu in top panel to **Lock User**
2. Click **Switch User** button (the round button at right bottom while entering password)
3. Select and relogin to current user
4. There will be 2 mouse cursors displays

Symptoms:

1. On my laptop: one of the cursor is frozen (just display on top level over any windows) and another works as normal
2. On virtual machine: both two cursors works (moves toghther) but one is smaller and another is bigger
3. Everything works well except the weird dual cursor

Currently i found two ways to remove one cursor:

1. Log out and relogin
2. Set scale to other value in Settings / Displays

Is there any way to avoid this issue ?